# PostgreSQL ST_Within query not working

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm using Psycopg2 and PostgreSQL to try and isolate points from within polygons for ArcGIS.
I generate a spatial condition from coordinates and can then pull all the points within that spatial condition using ST_Within.

If I have two spatial conditions and try and run this SQL query:

```
# Combine both spatial conditions using AND in the SQL query
        combined_spatial_condition = f"{catch_cond} AND {spatial_condition}"

        # Construct the SQL query
        sql_query = f"SELECT \"Date\", lai, lai2, lai3, fcover, \"Latitude\", \"Longitude\" FROM sdplus_good WHERE {combined_spatial_condition};"
```

I get all the points within {spatial_condition}
what  want is all the point that are in both {catch_cond} AND {spatial_condition}, and only those points.

If i run

```
 sql_query2 = f"SELECT \"Date\", lai , lai2, lai3, fcover ,\"Latitude\", \"Longitude\" FROM sdplus_good WHERE {spatial_condition};"
        sql_query3 = f"SELECT \"Date\", lai , lai2, lai3, fcover ,\"Latitude\", \"Longitude\" FROM sdplus_good WHERE {catch_cond};"
```

independently I get the correct set of points, so how do I run one SQL query to give the correct set?

Comment: What exactly *are* those conditions? Can you add an actual query from the PG server logs that is getting executed, including the conditions at query time?

Comment: If you don't provide the conditions, we can't tell you what's wrong. You state that you are running this for ArcGIS, but ArcGIS uses DA SearchCursor, not Psycopg2.

Comment: @geozelot the conditions are strings of length 32203 and 206535 characters each, created by a two functions, the first of which converts a shapefile to coordinates, and the second converts the coordinates to a spatial condition. I cant provide PG server logs because i'm running this in python.

Comment: @Vince I aqpologise, I'm not running it IN arcgis, but to generate data for arcgis. my scripts run in python using psycopg2. I can successfully extract the data for each individual condition, so I assume that the conditions are correct. all i want is to extract the data that appears in BOTH conditions

Comment: Probably an issue with your combined condition syntax. You can instead use a temporary table to: select from (select from ... where condition a) where condition b

Comment: The `AND` SQL operator is valid, and functional. Try to reproduce the behavior with a drastically simplified spatial constraint, then include that in the Question.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing an example of the conditions.  You could try `f"({catch_cond}) AND ({spatial_condition})"`

Answer (score 0):

Even though all the comments seemed to think that the conditions were the problem (I had noted that the conditions worked correctly individually) the problem has been solved by @jbalk 's comment.

If I could mark it as an answer I would :)

The issue was with the placement of the brackets in the building of the sql query.

Thankyou @jbalk, the query now runs perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Looks like you misread the comments

Comment: Glad I could help. Your conditions must be something like x OR y OR z, so you have to wrap those in parenthesis to do an AND comparison of the condition sets.

Comment: @jbalk yes, the conditions are a set of polygons (which is why they're very long and not suited to being posted on here) and I wanted to extract items from a 26 million row database that are in both polygons. I'm also ignoring the bot 

Comment: This is *exactly* what all comments about conditions were hinting at...

Comment: I just want to point out that the conditions were clearly the problem here.  If the conditions were simple and didn't include `OR`, like 100 AND 200, it would have worked.  But you must have the `OR` keyword in your condition sets, otherwise the original query without the parentheses would have worked correctly.  That's what people were asking about, albeit not super clearly.